Was Haider's party ever excluded from (or shunned by) European Parliament groups?
Related to the recent exclusion of the AfD from the ID group of the European Parliament due to exculpatory/apologist talk about the SS (by one AfD MEP--Krah), I'm curious if this is like a new bar that's being set by such right-wing groups in the EP. Because I recall that (Austrian politician) Jörg Haider made somewhat similar comments about the SS (something along the lines of not [all] being criminals, according to Haider--the statement seems pretty similar to me to what AfD's Krah said--see first source for a full quote--I don't want to detail its content more than necessary).
Was Haider's party (the FPÖ) excluded/avoided by European Parliament groups back then, as a result? (Yeah, Haider himself was not ever a MEP, but he led the party for decades, and they had a few MEPs for much of that time. Wikipedia does talk a bit about FPÖ's position in the EP [various] groups, but since 2007 or so, i.e. after Haider was out of the picture. So, IDK what happened in that regard in Haider's time.)

Note that the SS statement by Krah was sort of the final drop that made the barrel spill.  In April 2024 he also had a scandal because one of his close employees was arrested for working for the Chinese secret service and there was an investigation against Krah for allegedly taking money from Russia and China.

Partial answer with some preliminary research but I think the FPÖ was not a member of any political group in the European parliament during Haider's time.
First, the ID group was only founded in 2019 and even its predecessor Europe of Nations and Freedom was founded after Haiders death in 2008.
For the active time of Haider, quoting from the wikipedia article of the FPÖ:

In the early years of Haider's leadership, meetings were held with figures such as Jean-Marie Le Pen of the French National Front and Franz Schönhuber of the German Republicans.[133] In the late 1990s, however, he chose to distance himself from Le Pen, and refused to join Le Pen's EuroNat project. Following the FPÖ's entrance in government in 2000, Haider sought to establish his own alliance of right-wing parties. For his project, Haider tried to establish stable cooperations with the Vlaams Blok party in Belgium and the Northern League party in Italy, as well as some other parties and party groupings. In the end, the efforts to establish a new alliance of parties were not successful.[134]

It sounds like the FPÖ was not part of any formal group in the European parliament. So no discussion about any possible exclusion of the FPÖ happened because they weren't part of any group that could exclude them.

It was apparently part of this short lived group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity,_Tradition,_Sovereignty which is the predecessor to the predecessor of the ID group. But only with 1 person. And it failed because the Italian fascists were racist to Romanians with whom they shared this faction...

@haxor789 Good find. Pondering whether I should completely rewrite my answer to focus on that (and use mine as an explanation that there probably is no other group). Do you want to put that as your answer?

Nah you can have that for your answer :)

@haxor789: the FPÖ had more MEP seats in the 1996 and 1999 elections. I guess there wasn't any group that they could join then, so they sat by themselves... Wikipedia also mentions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euronat which existed since '97, but apparently the FPÖ and FN didn't agree on much then.

Interestingly "Fieschi (2000) and Startin (2010) note how the Austrian Freedom Party (FPÖ) avoided
allying with other radical right parties such as the French Front National (FN) in the late
1990s, due to the FPÖ’s goal of being accepted as a potential coalition partner by the centre-right after the 1999 general election".

According to Fieschi (2000), there were actually groups before the ITS, like the Technical Group of the European Right (roungly from '84 to '94). Fieschi discusses how this was set up as a 'technical' rather than 'political' group in the EP due to some rules. But the FPÖ did not have any MEP seats that far back.

Fieschi (2000) discusses this somewhat ancient history:

In the June 1999 elections the French
National Front (Front National) and the Austrian Freedom Party
(Freiheitliche Partei Österreichs) each acquired five seats, the Italian
National Alliance (Alleanza Nazionale) nine seats, the Northern League
(Lega Nord) four seats, the Belgian Flemish Block (Vlaams Blok) two,
and finally the Danish People’s Party (Dansk Folkeparti) a single seat.
Far-right MEPs make up just over 4% of the European Parliament’s
composition. With 26 MEPs in all (out of 626 seats) the far-right is
thus the smallest of ideological clusters represented in the European
Parliament in which even the next smallest cluster (the united left) is
nearly twice as well represented.[...]
The concern for respectability resulted—though not formally—to a
division between the Austrian Freedom Party and the National Alliance
on the one hand and the National Front and Flemish Block on the
other. Refusing to be associated with the latter two, both the former
deliberately avoided any type of cooperation with them—though the
National Alliance also refused to cooperate with the Freedom Party.
For the National Alliance, conscious of the need to maintain its
respectable image congruent with its repudiation of Fascism, any cooperation with a Flemish Block bent on amnesty for former Nazi collaborators was unimaginable, and relations with the Freedom Party taken as a potential liability. The Flemish Block and the National Front on the other hand, cooperated on a daily basis, sang one another’s praises in the European Parliament and shared a secretariat. The Austrian
Freedom party faced complete isolation.

So yeah, at least the Alleanza Nazionale shunned the FPÖ back then due to Nazi associations/perceptions, but the shunning was mutual.
